# What's the different between these two implementations

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, this

Snippet A:

```
DemoFilter =
  onConfirmed: (cb) ->
    cb()
a =
  onConfirmed: (callback) ->
    this.callback = callback
  confirm: ->
    this.callback()

b =
  init: ->
    a.onConfirmed =>
       DemoFilter.onConfirmed @mycallback
  mycallback: =>
    console.log this # output: {} or Object window on browser

b.init()
a.confirm()
```

Snippet B:

```
DemoFilter =
  onConfirmed: (cb) ->
    cb()
a =
  onConfirmed: (callback) ->
    this.callback = callback
  confirm: ->
    this.callback()

b =
  init: ->
    a.onConfirmed =>
       DemoFilter.onConfirmed =>
         console.log this # output: Object b
  # mycallback: =>
  #   console.log this

b.init()
a.confirm()
```

Why does these `console.log` output is not the same?

On Node environment:

A: output `{}`
B: output `Object b`

I found the compiled result is quite the same, I can not figure out why the result is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is that you're using simple objects rather than classes so `=>` isn't behaving the way you expect it to. When you say this:

```
o =
  m: =>
```

that's exactly the same as saying:

```
f = =>
o =
  m: f
```

and that means that `@` (AKA `this`) inside `m` is the global object (`window` in a browser or, AFAIK, an empty object in node.js) rather than `o` as you expect it to be.

When you say:

```
class C
  m: =>
```

CoffeeScript will bind `m` to the `C` *instance* when you say `o = new C`. If you use a plain object literal instead of a class, there is no special construction phase to set up the binding and no instance of a class for `=>` to bind the function to.

If we go back to your first case:

```
b =
  init: ->
    a.onConfirmed =>
       DemoFilter.onConfirmed @mycallback
  mycallback: =>
    console.log this
```

`mycallback` will be bound to whatever the global object is. Also, the value of `@` (AKA `this`) depends on how a function is called rather than where it is defined (baring bound functions of course) so if you say:

```
b.init()
```

then `@` inside `init` will be `b`. Then the anonymous function you hand to `a.onConfirmed`:

```
a.onConfirmed =>
   DemoFilter.onConfirmed @mycallback
```

will be bound to `b` because `@` is `b` when you define that function. But `mycallback` won't care because it has already been bound to the global object.

In your second case:

```
b =
  init: ->
    a.onConfirmed =>
       DemoFilter.onConfirmed =>
         console.log this
```

we again have `@` being `b` when `init` is called and the anonymous function passed to `a.onConfirmed` will again be bound to `b`. That means that when:

```
DemoFilter.onConfirmed => ...
```

is called, `@` will again be `b`. Here we have another anonymous bound function and since `@` is `b` at this level we have `this` (AKA `@`) being `b` when `console.log this` is called.

If you used classes instead of just objects:

```
class A
  onConfirmed: (@callback) ->
  confirm: ->
    @callback()

class B
  constructor: (a) ->
    a.onConfirmed =>
       DemoFilter.onConfirmed @mycallback
  mycallback: =>
    console.log @

a = new A
b = new B(a)
a.confirm()
```

then you should see the behavior you're expecting.